# Wireshark doesn't recoginize traffic from/to 80 port as HTTP protocol

Tags: networking, http, wireshark

I use wireshark to monitor the traffic of a desktop sofeware. I think the request is with http and it uses 80 port. But I don't know why not wireshark display it as http protocol so that I cannot view the request url and response message correctly.

screenshot of wireshark
[image: screenshot of wireshark]

Updated:
I noticed that it could not analyze may because there was a error while analyzing.

```
[Malformed Packet: HTTP]
  [Expert Info (Error/Malformed): Malformed Packet (Exception occurred)]
    [Malformed Packet (Exception occurred)]
    [Severity level: Error]
    [Group: Malformed]
```

Comment: Does the capture include the first packet of a response (the one that contains HTTP headers)?

Comment: Yes, but it couldn't analyze it. It showed: 
[Malformed Packet: HTTP]
    [Expert Info (Error/Malformed): Malformed Packet (Exception occurred)]
        [Malformed Packet (Exception occurred)]
        [Severity level: Error]
        [Group: Malformed]

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug sometime ago so if you have possibility download newer wireshark version and check again.

Check Analyze -> used protocols and check if HTTP is marked.

Check Edit -> preferences -> protocols -> http and check if the correct TCP ports are set.

Last thing which actually is workaround click Analyze -> Decode As then choose TCP port value 80 Current: HTTP and add another rule with port 443 now it should display HTTP protocols from well known ports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed the newest wireshark and checked analyze and edit setting, but that traffic on port 80 still cannot be analyzed correctly. I think it might be not a standard HTTP request.